# proofs regarding the spectrum of sets.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A,B ∈ M_n(ℝ).$

Suppose $α \in (A)$ and $β \in (B)$. i.e. suppose they are an eigenvalue of A and B respectively.

Prove or disprove : $α+β \in (A+B).$

Comment: If you have no idea whether the answer is yes or no, why don't you try to use a software like Matlab for $n=2$ with random matrices to have at least an idea whether it is yes or no ? And maybe, the first try will be the good one, do you see what I mean ?

Answer (score 0):

What are the spectra of the (diagonal!) matrices

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix} \ \ \text{and} \ \ B=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix} \ ?$$

and what is the spectra of $A+B$ ?

Conclusion ?

Comment: No comment on your side ?